# Surveys of the items of Erdős' "toolbox"

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, soft-question

Could you point out some survey papers and monographs that highlight the kernel of tricks, techniques, and tools that Paul Erdős employed the most in his research work (in particular in graph theory, combinatorics, and number theory)?

Comment: On the old version of MathOverflow, at one point, there was a maxim "MathOverflow is not for requests for people to write encyclopaedia entries for you." Times may have changed, but I really feel that this kind of question is just a fishing expedition

Comment: [You might try Tricki.](http://www.tricki.org/)

Comment: @YemonChoi I'm actually asking for references rather than for an extensive answer.

Comment: Your initial paragraph is not a quote. Indeed Rota explains that the pronouncement is not all that meaningful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems based on a misinterpretation of a quote.

Comment: It is an exact quote from the cited source, and I do not think it misrepresents Rota's ideas at all. Gowers in particular has written on 'tricks' or patterns of thought and problem-solving that are used in combinatorics.

Comment: Dear @quid, I *do* understand the original paragraph, and indeed I wrote "This is clearly an over-simplistic statement. Yet, I wonder if there is some truth in it."

Comment: @MariusKempe it might technically qualify as a quote but even this is debatable as the sentence does not start where the quote suggest. It is however taken **extremely** out of context.

Comment: @MariusKempe I like Rota's writing style but he was famously fond of being polemical, and Rota saying "X was like this" is not exactly gospel. The rest of the essays and anecdotes in "Indiscrete Thoughts" would bear this out

Comment: @YemonChoi the problem is that Rota does not even endorse the this. What he says is paraphrasing it is true, but it is true for  *every* mathematician. Moreover the start of the quoted half-sentence is "I was annoyed".

Comment: @quid Issues with the quote aside, I honestly don't see what is the problem in asking a question about finding some references that comment on the most frequently used items toolbox of a mathematician.

Comment: The problem is that you presuppose something. There is in principle no problem with asking about expositions of the work of Erdős, but then you should do this. Not repeat in confusing way a paraphrase of an insult.

Comment: @quid, it was just to give a bit of context for my question, but now I see that you're right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am not completely convinced of this question, but I will vote to reopen and see how things develop.

Comment: @Dal There are two books on the mathematics of Paul Erdős: *Graham, Nešetřil and Butler - The Mathematics of Paul Erdős I/II* (http://www.springer.com/mathematics/book/978-1-4614-7257-5)

Comment: @Fry, thank you very much for the reference: that is just what I was looking for. If the question is re-opened, you should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: The recent volume that came out of the Erdős centennial conference might also be of interest to you: http://www.springer.com/new+%26+forthcoming+titles+%28default%29/book/978-3-642-39285-6

Comment: I think not only is this question fine, but that the original version of the question is better.  A prominent mathematician makes a provocative claim about another prominent mathematician's mathematical work.  As long as this claim isn't actually libelous, then it's obviously on-topic for MathOverflow.  Who else would know the answer, other than research mathematicians?  Now Rota is well-known for his dramatic style, but they don't put a disclaimer on the cover of his book, and they don't warn you in intro grad classes, so many people who read that quote are going have the same question.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has mentioned the probabilistic method. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you @Fry, @so-calledfriendDon, and @DanPetersen (see comments) for these interesting references:

> Graham, Ronald L., Nešetřil, Jaroslav, Butler, Steve (eds.), *The
>   Mathematics of Paul Erdős* I and II, 2nd edition, Springer, 2013.
>
> Lovász, László, Ruzsa, Imre, Sós, Vera T. (eds.), *Erdös Centennial*,
>   Springer, 2013.
>
> Alon, Noga, Spencer, Joel H., *The probabilistic method*, 2nd edition,
>   Wiley-Interscience, 2000.

Answer (score 10):

You might get started with an Erdős commemoration appearing in this month's *Notices*:

> Reflections on Paul Erdős on His Birth Centenary. 
>   Krishnaswami Alladi and Steven Krantz, Coordinating Editors.  *Notices of the American Mathematical Society*, Feb. 2015, pp 121-143.  http://www.ams.org/notices/201502/rnoti-p121.pdf

It features several brief essays (1-2 pages each) by friends and collaborators of Erdős, each highlighting some particular aspect of his work, methods, and life.